# Implementing SmartyBC

Tags: php, templates, smarty, cs-cart

Just a small question for anyone out there that uses smarty. I am trying to pass PHP directly into my code, but when I do, the cached version cuts out the PHP and just prints it directly like so.

```
 <div class="dashboard-card-content">
 <?php

 $con = mysqli_connect(Nice,Try,Fly,Guy);
 $company_id = $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['auth']->value['user_id'];
 $company_id = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT company_id FROM cscart_users WHERE user_id = $company_id")->fetch_object()->company_id;
 $company_id = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT goal FROM cscart_companies WHERE company_id = $company_id")->fetch_object()->goal;
 echo "Your current goal is: ".$company_id; 
 ?>
```

This just prints all of it out on my webpage, so I tried using the following:

{Literal}

{Include_php}

{php}

And I just can't find a way to get my PHP code to go into my TPL how I want it. This is becoming really frustrating and all I want is for my cache files to leave the PHP code alone. Sorry if this is a dumb question but I have been researching this for a while. How do I implement SmartyBC so that I can still use PHP injections. And if using SmartyBC is a bad idea, can someone give me a dumbed down version of how to use a seperate PHP function page to set variables to show in the Template?

Answer (score 0):

Smarty is a template engine for presentation logic only. You cannot put application logic inside a template. It was possible in older versions of Smarty but fortunately not anymore. Just execute those funcions in a php file and pass the result to the template.

And yes, you can use SmartyBC: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/bc.tpl, but that's supposed to be used for compatibility with existing projects. It's a really bad idea and shouldn't be used for new projects.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use php in Smarty?

Put your logic into a class or function, and pass the data via the controller: `Registry::get('view')->assign('smarty_variable', $data)`, and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can create PHP function which gets necessary data from database. E.g.

```
function fn_get_company_goal($user_id)
{    
    $company_id = db_get_field("SELECT company_id FROM ?:users WHERE user_id = ?i, $user_id");
    $goal = db_get_field("SELECT goal FROM ?:companies WHERE company_id = ?i, $company_id");
    return $goal;
}
```

Put it to your addon. Then you can use it in the Smarty template in the following manner:

```
{$goal = $user_id|fn_get_company_goal}
```

Comment: I will try that thank you. Do I just create a PHP file in my functions folder such as "myfunc.php" and then it will just call automatically?

Comment: You can use the My changes module and the following file:

app/addons/my_changes/func.php